# Errors with Java Swing - Unknown changes

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I have been working on a Swing based java program for a while now, today I have been editing the JComboBox (using Netbeans so I am unable to directly edit the code for it), at some point between edits the below errors have sudddenly appeared.
Obviously at this point there is far too much code involved to post, but does anyone have any idea / experience of what may have caused this?

I have made no direct changes to the source code since before this error began, but despite all efforts to undo all changes made today it has made no impact on these errors. I have even tried closing netbeans and restarting it on the off chance that it was just playing up.

Also, what is the $1 at the end of Application indicating? I have not seen this previously

Thanks for any and all suggestions.

08-Oct-2010 14:07:07 org.jdesktop.application.Application$1 run

```
SEVERE: Application class nodeview.NodeViewApp failed to launch
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at nodeview.NodeViewView.<init>(NodeViewView.java:49)
        at nodeview.NodeViewApp.startup(NodeViewApp.java:19)
        at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Application class nodeview.NodeViewApp failed to launch
        at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:177)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at nodeview.NodeViewView.<init>(NodeViewView.java:49)
        at nodeview.NodeViewApp.startup(NodeViewApp.java:19)
        at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
        ... 8 more
```

As requested, the code from line 37 through to 50 from NodeViewView

```
    messageTimer.setRepeats(false);
    int busyAnimationRate = resourceMap.getInteger("StatusBar.busyAnimationRate");
    for (int i = 0; i < busyIcons.length; i++) {
        busyIcons[i] = resourceMap.getIcon("StatusBar.busyIcons[" + i + "]");
    }
    busyIconTimer = new Timer(busyAnimationRate, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            busyIconIndex = (busyIconIndex + 1) % busyIcons.length;
            statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(busyIcons[busyIconIndex]);
        }
    });
    idleIcon = resourceMap.getIcon("StatusBar.idleIcon");
   statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(idleIcon); //49
   progressBar.setVisible(false); //50
```

Comment: You should really look into coding swing by hand in the future. I know I'm not on topic, but just think about it ;)

Comment: You can edit the source of your Swing applications. When you open the class for editing, and looking at your pretty picture, the bar directly above that has a "source" and "design" button.

Comment: once you find your source, post NodeViewView (a couple relevent lines on and around 49 will be good)

Comment: I have posted the relevant lines above. I understand how to view and edit the source, I just chose to use the GUI builder just to speed up the process (which has now kinda backfired!) but Swing is not one of my strong points so I do find it hard to interpret what it is doing.
Although, it would probably help to try coding it by hand to help with problems like this :)

Edit: Also, those lines were generated by Netbeans and have been present since the project was created, unless I have accidentally overwritten something and not realised.

Comment: Look at your code and ensure statusAnimationLabel is being initialized. That would be the source of your null pointer exception. idleIcon can be null without it throwing any exception, so it has to be statusAnimationLabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NodeViewView.java:49` is where you will find the error.  Most like an object has not been initialized properly and you're trying access a method or member variable of that object.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Using this I tracked down where idleIcon was initialised, it all appeared to be ok when I realised there was no call to actually initialise any of the swing code (all the code generated by Netbeans) and that was due to me clearly accidentally deleting the one line of;
        initComponents();
Schoolboy error, but at least I found it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You really need to look at the code for `NodeViewView` and `NodeViewApp` to figure this out. Please post the relevant sections out of these classes.

Edit: `statusAnimationLabel` is null then isn't it. Note that passing a null value to `setIcon(Icon icon)` won't throw a NPE.